# What slows down Java if CPU usage low, hdd usage low, memory usage low?

Tags: java

So basicly the question is as above. I have written a program, that reads csv files and makes some calculations on the fly. I posted logic of the code below, I see no bottleneck through resorse monitor. It must be bottleneck somewhere I cannot monitor through monitor resources.

So where is a bottleneck I ask? If its not cpu neither hdd neither ram?

Maybe its ram to cpu link that is weak link, because files quite small around 30 mb each, so its being loaded to ram in a second. CPU usage around 30% so if file already in the ram and usage low than maybe ram - cpu link is slowing down performance? Ram used by java only 300mb, any suggestions?

I know its more hardware question than programming question, but nevertheless its Java using hardware so maybe someone can explain to me where the weak link.

My specs: core i3-540, hdd 7200rm seagate, ram ddr3 8gb

```
for (int z = 0; z < f.size(); z++){

BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
String Line2 = br2.readLine();
while((Line2 = br2.readLine())!= null){


if(){
do some calculation
}
if(){
do some calculation
}
if(){
do some calculation
}
}
System.out.println(results);
```

Comment: 30mb of text is a lot of lines, and you seems to process `f.size()` 30mb files line by line. I would try with one 1mb file

Comment: Can't help but to smile when I realize we're in times when you can semi-legitimately describe a 30MB file as "small".

Comment: Everything is percepted by comparison, so when I say 30 mb is small, I say so because I processed 8gb csv files. When I read 8 gb csv file I can understand why it takes some time to process the file, the bottleneck is my hdd, which reads max 50 mb per second, but when I use small files, and it literally makes calculations around 12 seconds per file (in total 30 files), I cannot understand it, given that CPU usage is only 30 percent, with whole bunch of programms running in background, with hdd usage 0, with whole bunch of ram free, I just cannot accept it, so the question still open...

Comment: I dont process f.size(), the for loop just iterates through files, f.size() is actually file names, 30 in total. Cannot say process either, for cpu usage is around 30%... so it is a light work for cpu, hdd is not used as well, ram is free... so what the heck make it so slow?

Comment: BufferedReader has one more constructor which sets the size of the internal buffer. Making it larger(around 1MB) might help.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, tried just now 4000 and 20000, results pretty much the same, former few seconds faster than later.

Comment: It seems there is some kind of memory swapping going on. One more experiment - Read all the lines of the file in a single pass and store it in a list. Process it later. Better still spawn a threads and do it concurrently.

Comment: My first attempt to code the programm was exactly reading to arraylist, it is really a performance hurdle to read to arraylist, files over 2gb impossible to process, it just load pc to 100% and doing nothing, throwing some memory warnings. So no, reading from file directly much faster, I think I will try to multithread.

Comment: Ok, I multithreaded to 4 cores the code, and now I got 99% usage on all cores, total time to complete 2:44 vs previous 4:07, still sucks given that later CPU usage only around 30-35%, and loading it 99% gives you only around 40% speed increase, still not very happy, but its better than nothing, right? Now however I have to figure out how to synchronize output :) But now I am afraid synchronization will eliminate big deal of 40% boost...

Answer (score 0):

You can test what is the bottle neck by taking different parts out of the equation.  To take out the CPU, just read the files and don't do anything else. To take out the disk, keep reading the same file again and again, assuming it fits in your file cache.  Compare this to the time for everything.

Comment: As I already said, its not cpu, not hdd, not ram, because I can monitor them and see under load what percentage they are utilized. So it must be something that I cannot measure through resource monitor window in windows, thats why I ask, maybe some experienced dude can point out what the problem is.

Comment: Unless you know what it is, you need to dissect the problem. It might not show CPU if it is waiting for locking, it might not show wait for IO if it waiting for a network access (Note many functions do this without you knowing e.g. SecureRandom)  System monitoring does a low impact attempt to tell what is happening, but is often very inaccurate.